# Allow space in scatterplot variable name R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a shiny app in Rstudio. The app creates two plots - a time series and a scatterplot. The variables being plotted are `Water Temperature` and `Air Temperature`. The time series plot handles the space in the variable names with no problem however, I get an error with the scatterplots associated with the variable names.

The error is:

```
Warning: Error in parse: <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
1: Water Temperature
          ^
```

or

```
Warning: Error in parse: <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
1: Air Temperature
        ^
```

I suspect these errors have something to do with the space between Water/Air and Temperature. It is critical to keep the space rather than replace it with an underscore or some other space filler. How can I maintain the space in the variable name when making scatterplots?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Create example dataset
set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(
  Time = rep(seq(1,10,1), times = 2),
  Site = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 10),
  Water_Temperature = round(rnorm(20, mean = 20, sd = 5)),
  Air_Temperature = round(rnorm(20, mean = 25, sd = 3))
)

dat <- dat %>%
  rename(`Water Temperature` = Water_Temperature,
         `Air Temperature` = Air_Temperature)

dat_long <- dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("Water Temperature","Air Temperature"),
               names_to = 'Variable',
               values_to = 'Value') %>%
  arrange(Site, Time)

# Define user interface for time series and scatterplot
ui.R <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Example", titleWidth = 350),
  dashboardSidebar(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML("
          .sidebar-footer {
            text-align: center;
          }
          .sidebar-logo {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
          }
          .sidebar-menu a span {
            font-size: 24px;
          }
        ")
      )
    ),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Time Series", tabName = "time_series", icon = icon("chart-line")),
      menuItem("Scatterplot", tabName = "scatter_plot", icon = icon("chart-line"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "time_series",
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title = "Time Series",
            status = "primary",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 2,
            selectInput("siteInput", "Select Site", choices = unique(dat_long$Site)),
            selectInput("variableInput", "Select Variable", choices = unique(dat_long$Variable))
          ),
          box(
            title = "Plot",
            status = "primary",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 10,
            plotOutput("timeSeriesPlot", height = "700px")
          )
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "scatter_plot",
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title = "Scatterplot",
            status = "primary",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 2,
            selectInput("siteInput2", "Select Site", choices = unique(dat_long$Site)),
            selectInput("xAxisInput", "Select X-axis Variable:", choices = unique(dat_long$Variable)),
            selectInput("yAxisInput", "Select Y-axis Variable:", choices = unique(dat_long$Variable))
          ),
          box(
            title = "Plot",
            status = "primary",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 10,
            plotOutput("scatterPlot", height = "700px")
          )
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "site_info",
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            selectInput("siteInput3", "Select Site", choices = unique(dat_long$Site)),
            column(4, dataTableOutput('table'))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server
server.R <- function(input, output) {
  output$timeSeriesPlot <- renderPlot({
    filteredData <- dat_long %>%
      filter(Site == input$siteInput, Variable == input$variableInput)
    
    variableName <- unique(filteredData$Variable)
    yLabel <- ifelse(variableName == "Water Temperature", expression(Water~Temperature~(degree*C)),
                     ifelse(variableName == "Air Temperature", expression(Air~Temperature~(degree*C))))
    
    ggplot(filteredData, aes(x = Time, y = Value)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,1)) +
      labs(x = "", y = yLabel,
           title = paste('Site:', input$siteInput)) +
      theme_bw()
  })
  
  output$scatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    filteredData2 <- dat_long %>%
      filter(Site == input$siteInput2)
    
    # Create a reactive label to display the units for the selected variable on the x and y axes
    xLabel <- reactive({
      switch(input$xAxisInput[1],
             `Air Temperature` = expression(Air~Temperature~(degree*C)),
             `Water Temperature` = expression(Water~Temperature~(degree*C)))
    })
    
    yLabel <- reactive({
      switch(input$yAxisInput[1],
             `Air Temperature` = expression(Air~Temperature~(degree*C)),
             `Water Temperature` = expression(Water~Temperature~(degree*C)))
    })
    
    ggplot(filteredData2, aes_string(x = input$xAxisInput, y = input$yAxisInput)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = xLabel(), y = yLabel(),
           title = paste('Site:', input$siteInput2)) +
      theme_bw()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui.R, server = server.R)
```

Time series plot works
[image]
Scatterplot does not work
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting that `aes_string` can't deal with spaces. However, you can fix this by switching to the `.data` pro-noun which as `aes_string` is deprecated it also the recommend way to do (see `?aes_string`), i.e. use

```
ggplot(filteredData2, 
    aes(x = .data[[input$xAxisInput]], y = .data[[input$yAxisInput]])
) +
```

Moreover, you are trying to make your scatterplot from the long data which has no variables `Water/Air Temperature`. For the scatterplot you have to use the wide dataset, i.e. use

```
filteredData2 <- dat %>%
      filter(Site == input$siteInput2)
```

[image]